# MKAnnotation text to UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, mkannotation

Hi is it possible that when I clicked the annotation, one label gets the title of the annotation and other label the subtitle Some thing like:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
label1.text = annotation.title;
label2.text = annotation.subtitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {
   MapAnnotation *mAnnotation = (MapAnnotation*)view.annotation; 
   label1.text = mAnnotation.title;
   label2.text = mAnnotation.subtitle;
  }
```

Comment: The annotation is accessible through view.annotation (view is the MKAnnotationView not the id<MKAnnotation>).  So it should be `(MapAnnotation*)view.annotation`.

Comment: worked perfectly with MKPointAnnotation *mAnnotation = (MKPointAnnotation*)view.annotation;

Answer (score 1):

Since MKAnnotation is a protocol, you'll have to define your own class that implements the protocol.

```
@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;    
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;


@end
```

And then synthesis the above properties in .m file

```
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;
```

In MapViewController Class(i.e controller class with mkmapview), you need to implement below code.

```
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = latitude; // latitude float value for location
        region.center.longitude =longitude; // longitude float value for location
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY);
        MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
        ann.title = @"Title";
        ann.subtitle = @"subTitle";
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];

        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I already added the annotations using a json, now the thing I need is when the annotations are clicked the labels get the text from the title and subtitle.

Comment: Try This this

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {
   MapAnnotation *mAnnotation = (MapAnnotation*)view; 
   label1.text = mAnnotation.title;
   label2.text = mAnnotation.subtitle;
  }